# The Rotate and Shift operations in a Finite Field

Tags: finite-fields, boolean-algebra

Do the Rotate and Shift operations in $GF_2$ have simple expressions in a finite field?

The Rotate operation $ROT[x,n]$ left rotates by n-bits. So $ROT[(0,1,1,1),2]=(1,1,0,1)$.

The Shift operation $SHIFT[x,n]$ left shifts by n-bits. So $SHIFT[(0,1,1,1),2]=(1,1,0,0)$.

So for SHIFT, a n-right shift is the same thing as multiplication by 2^n... at least in the binary integer world. For example: $37=(1,0,0,1,0,1)_2$ and $37*2^2=148=(1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0)_2$... Now since the number of digits in 37 was initially 6 and we are therefore bounded by $2^6$, $148=(0,1,0,1,0,0)$ which is the right shift of $37$ by $2$ to the right.

Comment: Multiplication by $2^n$ (with $n>0$) is the zero map in $GF_2$ or any field of characteristic $2$.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add clarifications in my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "simple" expressions? polynomials in the entries of the tuples, perhaps?

Comment: The effect of these operations in a finite field $GF(2^n)$ depends on how you interpret the bits as an element of the field. If you are using a normal basis, then rotating the coordinates to the left is equivalent to squaring the element. If you are using a monomial basis consisting of powers of a primitive element, then shifting to the left amounts to multiplying the primitive element giving the basis. As long as you conditionally (on overflow) follow the shift by XORring with the sequence of coefficients of the minimal polynomial of the primitive element.

Comment: Jyrki is right... I shifted in the wrong direction but this should not change the spirit of the question. Thanks for noticing... I'll edit the question.

Comment: ...and Dilip's right. Rotation makes sense as a primitive operation in the ring $GF(2)[x]/(x^n+1)$. This ring is never a field though.

Answer (score 2):

There is no expression in what you call $GF_2$ *per se* for shifting a sequence of bits (elements of $GF_2$) cyclically (or rotating it)
for the simple reason that the sequence is not an element of $GF_2$; the individual components (bits comprising the sequence) are in $GF_2$, but not the sequence itself.  Now, if you interpret the $n$-bit sequence
$(c_{n-1},c_{n-2}, \ldots, c_1, c_0)$ as the *integer* $C = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c_i 2^i$, then it is true that a rotation by $k$ places, $0 \leq k < n$, that is,
$$(c_{n-1},c_{n-2}, \ldots, c_1, c_0) \longrightarrow 
(c_{n-k-1}, c_{n-k-2}, \ldots, c_0,c_{n-1}, c_{n-2}, \ldots, c_{n-k})$$ gives the sequence corresponding to the integer $D^{(k)}$ where 
$$D^{(k)} = \begin{cases}2^kC \bmod (2^n-1), & C \neq 2^n-1,\\
2^n-1, & C = 2^n-1,\end{cases}$$
but this is not an operation in the 
finite field $GF_2$.  Note that the special calculation for $(1,1,\ldots 1) \leftrightarrow C=2^n-1$ is needed to avoid getting a $0$ result when the 
mod $2^n-1$ operation is carried out on $2^k(2^n-1)$.

Try it, you will like it.  Your $ROT[(0,1,1,1),2]=(1,1,0,1)$ corresponds
to $7$ being transformed to $2^2\times 7 = 28 \equiv 13 \bmod 15.$

Alternatively, if you interpret the sequence as the coefficients of 
a *polynomial* $C(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}c_i x^i$, then rotating by $k$ bits
results in the bit sequence corresponding to the *polynomial*
$$D^{(k)}(x) = x^k C(x) \bmod (x^n-1)$$
where both $C(x)$ and $D^{(k)}(x)$ belong to a mathematical structure
denoted by $\mathbb F_2[x]$ and called the *ring* of polynomials in
$x$ with coefficients in $\mathbb F_2 = GF_2$. Once again, these
polynomials are not "in" $GF_2$.

Comment: Could we say that they are in $GF_2^n$ for the n-bit sequence you defined?

Comment: In ordinary mathematical usage, $GF_2^n$ would mean the vector space of $n$-tuples of bits while the _field_ of $2^n$ elements would be denoted by $\mathbb F_{2^n}$ while engineers such as myself and computer scientists might prefer GF$(2^n)$ or $GF_{2^n}$ that is what you are comfortable with. Any $n$-bit vector can be said to be in the vector space $GF_2^n$ and rotation is a primitive operation there equivalent to a change of basis. The $n$-bit sequence can be said to be in the _field_ $GF_{2^n}$ but _which_ element of the field it is depends on what _basis_ you are using. (continued)

Comment: As @JyrkiLahtonen pointed out, if a _normal_ basis is used, then shifting by one place amounts to _squaring_ (or square-rooting depending on which ordering of the basis is used!) the element. Otherwise, the rotation operation is once again a change of basis operation in the field.

Answer (score 1):

These operations aren't well-defined on a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ in the first place. To define them you need to pick an encoding of elements of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ as strings of $n$ bits, and there isn't a distinguished such encoding; you get such an encoding from any basis of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$, but there isn't a distinguished basis, and there are other encodings that don't even have this form.